# Is there a LINQ function that checks whether list of objects contains an attribute that matches a dictionary value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have an <int, string> dictionary and I am trying to check an IEnumerable of objects to see, whether a particular attribute is contained in the dictionary. I am aware of Contains but I can't seem to reverse it if it makes sense.

If it were just one value I'd be fine but I need the list to go through the whole dictionary for each item in the list.

Currently I am using this:

```
foreach (var item in model)
                {
                    if (dictionary.Values.Contains(object.Attribute))
                    {
                        list.Add(object);
                    }
                }
```

Thank you!

Comment: `.Where(x => dictionary.Values.Contains(x.PropertyYouWantToCheckOnTheObject))`?

Comment: If it's to add to a list, maybe a select(many?) would be more appropriate

Comment: I'd probably start by building a `HashSet<string>` from the values in the dictionary, unless you know there won't be many.

Comment: @Irwene from the `foreach` loop it just looks like they want to add the entire item to the list (which I imagine is 'empty' before this loop, which we can't tell without more code context, hint hint @Drinkbeergetmoney) as long as one of its properties exists in the `Dictionary`, so I don't think a `Select[Many]` is needed for a particular property.

Comment: @Daevin True, I wrote my comment on a headache, should have taken the time to reread

Comment: @Irwene oof, sorry to hear. I had one earlier so I sympathize. Stay Strong lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code below, and if you want to play with it use [this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrMFx0). This takes Jon Skeet's advice to use a `HashSet`.

```
// your dictionary of items
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(0, "Zero");
dict.Add(2, "Two");
dict.Add(4, "Four");

// as suggested by Jon Skeet, create a HashSet to be more performant
var hs = new HashSet<string>(dict.Values);

// list of unfiltered items
var list = new List<dynamic>()
{
    new { Id = 0, Name = "Zeroth", PropertyYouWantToCheck = "Zero" },
    new { Id = 1, Name = "First", PropertyYouWantToCheck = "One" },
    new { Id = 2, Name = "Second", PropertyYouWantToCheck = "Two" },
    new { Id = 3, Name = "Third", PropertyYouWantToCheck = "Three" },
    new { Id = 4, Name = "Fourth", PropertyYouWantToCheck = "Four" },
};

// LINQ query to filter the list
var filteredList = list.Where(i => hs.Contains(i.PropertyYouWantToCheck));

// output the name of the filtered items
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filteredList.Select(fl => fl.Name)));
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks amazing! I will definitely look into HashSets more aswell.